# DataCacheFactoryConfiguration using local memory only?

Tags: azure, azure-caching

Is there anyway to configure DataCache provider to rely on local memory only for cache?

For performance reasons, bunch of my developers do not use Azure emulator when testing their Azure stuff, but debug the Web apps directly.

We're not using web.configs at all to drive configuration for cache and it would certainly be nice to be able to inject a setting into our custom configuration utility that in such-n-such mode, DataCache does not try to consume Shared or Dedicated Azure cache but simply local memory on the PC. (InProc - HttpRunTime.Cache)